# Why a member function of Mainwindow can call a member of Qlabel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am quite new in C++ and just started learning Qt in C++. I found the code below confuses me a bit. What it does just create a label in a window.

The mainwindow.cpp is

```
    1   #include "mainwindow.h"
    2   #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    3   
    4   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    5       QMainWindow(parent),
    6       ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    7   {
    8       ui->setupUi(this);
    9   }
   10   
   11   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
   12   {
   13       delete ui;
   14   }
   15   
   16   void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
   17   {
   18       ui->label->setText("button is clicked");  
   19        
   21   }
```

Main.cpp is

```
    1   #include "mainwindow.h"
    2   #include <QApplication>
    3   
    4   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    5   {
    6       QApplication a(argc, argv);
    7       MainWindow w;
    8       w.show();
    9   
   10       return a.exec();
   11   }
```

Mainwindow.h is

```
 1  #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    2   #define MAINWINDOW_H
    3   
    4   #include <QMainWindow>
    5   
    6   namespace Ui {
    7   class MainWindow;
    8   }
    9   
   10   class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
   11   {
   12       Q_OBJECT
   13   
   14   public:
   15       explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   16       ~MainWindow();
   17   
   18   private slots:
   19       void on_pushButton_clicked();
   20   
   21   private:
   22       Ui::MainWindow *ui;
   23   };
   24   
   25   #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

My confusion is ui-->label->setText("botton is clicked").
My understanding the ui is a private member of MainWindow, which is inherited from Qwidget. But label just a member of Qlabel. Why can a base class member call a member of the derived class? or could someone please just explain me why this is right?

Thank you guys very much

Comment: *But label just a member of Qlabel*, that is not correct, ui->label is an object of the QLabel class, it is not a member of QLabel, the composition is being implemented, this makes an easy and agile design, Qt implements ui to be able to handle the design in a simple way generated by Qt Designer, an interesting advantage is that if the design is modified the MainWindow class is not modified, only the Ui::MainWindow class is modified.

Comment: Thank you very much. whether each time I add something to the mainwindow.ui, such as a label, it will be automatically added into the private member ui? This is why ui->lable is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Your class "MainWindow" is derived from QMainWindow. Ui is a namespace at the global level; it contains a class named MainWindow, this is not your "MainWindow". ui is a private member of your class of type Ui::MainWindow, and it contains the QLabel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. May I ask why the private member contain QLabel? Is it because I set up a mainwindow object, which contains a ui member. This ui member will generate the mainwindow.ui under Forms. Whenever I put something like a label, it will be added into the private member ui?

Comment: Qt uses several external tools to generate C++ code that is compiled into the final executable. One of the tools is uic.exe [link](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/uic.html). The input to this tool is an xml file with a ".ui" extention, the output of this tool is a file named ui_ORIGINAL_UI_FILENAME.h. The output header in your case is ui_mainwindow.h. Your input file was mainwindow.ui; which most likely was generated by the Qt Designer. In the Qt Designer a QLabel named label must have been added. This QLabel is a member of the class defined within the generated ui_mainwindow.h file.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things: **an object of a class and a member of a class**. An **object** of a class is an instance of a Class. For example, you declare some integer variable `int n`. Here, `int` is a class and `n` is an object (or instance) of class `int`. **Members** of a class are anything you declare inside your class under **private**, **protected** and **public** keywords.

Your `MainWindow` class **has a member** called `ui` (its declared inside the class `MainWindow` in your `mainwindow.h` file). That `ui` is, at the same time, an **object of** `Ui::MainWindow` class (if you open `ui_mainwindow.h` file and look at `Ui_MainWindow` class, you should understand how it works).

So in your function (slot):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("button is clicked");  
}
```

you are calling a private member of MainWindow `ui` (which is an object of another class). `ui` has a public member `label` which is object (or instance) of a QLabel class.

Sorry for my English. Hope it makes a sense.